# Serilog sink file retainedFileCountLimit with minimum level to error

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am trying to set a minimum level while creating a logger, as reported below:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Error()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.Async(a =\> a.File(this.logFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: this.retention, shared: true, outputTemplate: MY_TEMPLATE))
.CreateLogger();
```

With this code, the retention is not applied, and all the previous files are not deleted, as the retainedFileCountLimit would be not set.
If I set the minimum level to debug with `.MinimumLevel.Debug()`, files are deleted as foreseen by value of retainedFileCount.

I tried removing the `shared` mode and I used `WriteTo.File(...)` instead of `WriteTo.Async(...)`:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.File(this.logFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: this.retention, outputTemplate: MY_TEMPLATE)
.CreateLogger();
```

But the problem persists also with this code.

How could I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The Async wrapping should definitely make no difference. Are you doing at least one log statement that's triggering a write in each instance to trigger trimming? i.e. if the log statements are being filtered out, it may not get to the sink, and hence trimming may not take place.

Comment: (migrated from https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/283, where I asked the same questions - thanks for taking the time to move it)